# Split value of string within array of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I've an arrays of arrays called `arr` and I want to split the second value of each array. This means, if I've `0-6` I would like to modify it to `'0','6'`

What I have:

```
arr = [['PROVEEDOR', '0-6', '11111'], ['tiempo ida pulidor', '6-14', '33333']]
```

What I would like to have:

```
arr = [['PROVEEDOR', '0', '6', '11111'], ['tiempo ida pulidor', '6', '14', '33333']]
```

How can I do this conversion? It's always the second value, and always have two numbers. I know I've to use `.split('-')` but I know dont know to make it work here to make the replacement, as I've to iterate between all the arrays included in `arr`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to do it inplace:

```
In [83]: arr = [['PROVEEDOR', '0-6', '11111'], ['tiempo ida pulidor', '6-14', '33333']]

In [84]: for i in arr:
    ...:     i[1:2]=i[1].split('-')

In [85]: arr
Out[85]: [['PROVEEDOR', '0', '6', '11111'], ['tiempo ida pulidor', '6', '14', '33333']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you adapt your answer to the desired result? You're getting another array `['0', '6']` for the second position and I would like to have two different values, `'0','6'`

Comment: @Borja That's weird, the updates doesn't show to you?

Comment: @KobiK actually I see your comment 1 min after my editing, idk why ;P

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan np, that would make `arr` `[['PROVEEDOR', ['0', '6'], '11111'], ['tiempo ida pulidor', ['6', '14'], '33333']]`

Comment: @zhangxaochen yes I tried at my system Thanks! nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
arr = [['PROVEEDOR', '0-6', '11111'], ['tiempo ida pulidor', '6-14', '33333']]

new_arr = []
for x in arr:
    new_val = [x[0]]
    new_val.extend(x[1].split('-'))
    new_val.append(x[2])
    new_arr.append(new_val)

print new_arr
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def splitfirst(a):
    a[1:2] = a[1].split('-')
    return a
newarr = [splitfirst(a) for a in arr]
```

What is going on? Well, you can assign to a slice, replacing that portion of the list with a new sequence. That is what the line

```
a[1:2] = [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

does. It replaces the slice `1:2` (element with index `1` up to but not including element with index `2`) with the new sequence - the result of our splitting in this case.

Since this solution relies on assigning to a slice, which is a statement, we can't do this without a separate function. Wait. I'm going to go and see if I can find something...

**EDIT:** Onliner for those who like that:

```
[a.__setslice__(1, 2, a[1].split('-')) or a for a in arr]
```

What is going on here? Well... actually exactly the same as before, but using the magic method `__setslice__` instead of the syntactic sugar of slice assignment. I use the `or a` part of the expression to produce the `arr` element, since `__setslice__` returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in arr:
   elems = a.pop(1).split('-')
   a.insert(1, elems[0])
   a.insert(2, elems[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing original array (with copy):

```
result = [[ar[0]] + ar[1].split('-') + ar[2:] for ar in arr]
```

In-place solution:

```
for ar in arr:
    x,y = ar[1].split('-')
    ar[1] = x
    ar.insert(2, y)
```